# Using fira-math with pdflatex

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, sans-serif

Can I use the `fira-math` font with `pdflatex`?

With the `sfmath` package I can activate a sans serif font for the math but would like to use the matching font fira-math (https://github.com/firamath/firamath)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{sfmath}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[1]

$$x_{1,2} = -\frac{p}{2} \pm \sqrt{ \left( \frac{p}{2} \right)^2 - q   } $$

\blindtext[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you can't use the fira-math font as it's opentype, I suppose in principle (as with the fira text fonts) the font could be split up into 8bit fonts and suitable pdftex compatible tex support set up, but that's quite a bit of work unless someone has done it already. Can you not use luatex or xetex?

Comment: I can, but for speed reasons I usually prefer pdflatex.

Comment: A major reason for it being faster is it doesn't have to handle fonts with tens of thousands of characters.....

Comment: A suggestion unrelated to the OP: Fira Sans has relatively large glyph, so a larger leading is recommended, i.e., `\linespread{1.16}\selectfont` in your preamble. This is just like the `\linespread{1.05}\selectfont` for Palatino.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not to mention that the OpenType Fira Math is still in development and many glyphs are still missing. My guess is that it is not worth it to convert Fira Math into pdfTeX-compatible format at this stage.